# ShouldQuote putting quotes around all fields in a row instead just the ones I need

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm only want to put quotes around a fields that are dates and no other field.
I wrote a function to pass to `ShouldQuote` to return `true` if the field is a DateTime. But it's putting quotes around every field in the row.  I stepped through the code and verified that the result returned from my function is false, but the field still has quotes around it.  Am I doing something wrong or this the intended functionality of ShouldQuote?

```
private bool ShouldQuote(string field, WritingContext context)
{
   DateTime date;
   var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(field, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
   return result;
}
var config = new Configuration();
config.ShouldQuote = ShouldQuote;
```

Comment: Check whether config.QuoteAllFields is true? On the face of it, what you have looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an earlier version of CsvHelper?  You would need `CsvConfiguration` with the current version 15.0.5.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var records = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "Quinn", Date = "05/20/2020" }
        };

        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            ShouldQuote = ShouldQuote
        };

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool ShouldQuote(string field, WritingContext context)
    {
        DateTime date;
        var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(field, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
        return result;
    }
}
```